# How to overcome 65535 lines limitation in CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd

I need to copy contents of file1 in file2.
I am using the following command in CMD (Win 7):

```
more /P < file1.rej >file2.DAT
```

The copying fails at line no. 65535.
How to overcome this limitation?

Comment: You can't as long as you use the `more` command. Why don't you use the `copy` command for copying a file? By the way: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: In my case file1.rej is in Unix format, I need file2.DAT in Windows format to solve EOL conversion issues. Using ```copy``` or ```type``` command the UNIX format EOL is also getting copied. I have found a solution.   Now am using powershell  command  - ```Get-Content file1.txt | Out-File out.txt ```

Comment: Well, this is a very important information that should have been included in the question. To convert to Windows EOLs, you could: 1. use `find /V "" < "file1.rej" > "file2.dat"` when the line length limit of ~ 4K does not disturb, or 2. `sort /R /+65535 /REC 65535 "file1.rej" | sort /R /+65535 /REC 65535 /O "file2.dat"` with a line length limit of ~ 64K; there is no limitation of the number of lines (besides available memory)…